# Microsoft Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, printing

My gradebook spreadsheet has student assignment headings in columns B-H and their final grade average in column I. Student names are in Column A in descending order.

How can I print out Column Headings and each student's name individually to send to them on a single sheet of paper. I do not want all students listed on this print out--only the student I am sending the grade to.

Comment: If you don't want to get involved in VBA code, you can just highlight the columns you want to print, then print selection.  You can select multiple separate columns by holding down the CTRL key.  Of course, you will have to do this for each student, but that may be easier than trying to code it.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and fastest way to do this is to create a Microsoft Word document and use the Mail Merge feature to read your Excel spreadsheet.

It took me about three minutes to create a template file that would meet your needs.

Every student ends up on an individual page and you can print all of the reports at once.  In addition, you never have to change the template file after you create it unless you add more columns to your spreadsheet.

[image: Sample Excel Student Grade Book]
[image: Sample Word Individual Student Report with Mail Merge Fields]
[image: Sample Mail Merge Output File]

Comment: Very clever. +1